# Check if SF Symbol exists Swift

Tags: swift, image, swiftui, sf-symbols

I want to display a SwiftUI Image with a number. I might do so like this:

```
let number = 13
Image(systemName: "\(number).square.fill")
```

However, not every number has an SF Symbol — what if I wanted to display `134.square.fill` but discovered that there isn't one, crashing the app?

How can I check if an SF Symbol exists without crashing the app?

Comment: I don't know if this was different before, but my apps won't crash if the symbol image does not exist. There will be simply no image, just blank.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following code will show the question mark symbol, if one for the number does not exist. But you can adapt it to do anything.

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        let number = 144

        return VStack {
            Image(uiImage: UIImage(systemName: "\(number).square.fill") ?? UIImage(systemName: "questionmark.square.fill")!)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `UIImage(systemName: "\(number).square.fill") ?? UIImage(systemName: "questionmark.square.fill")!`

Comment: @LeoDabus Yeap, I updated the answer to include your improvement. Cheers.

Comment: you could use my enum, which supports use of Image with SFSymbols as an enum: https://github.com/luckychris/SFSymbols. Then you know at compile time wether it exists and you get autocompletion for free.

Comment: When you use `Image(uiImage: UIImage(....))` you lose the ability to apply attributes like `foregroundColor` and `font`. If you want to keep those, then you should check if `UIImage(systemName: ...)` returns nil or not, then load it directly using `Image(systemName: ...)` I don't personally like this loading the image twice but it seems you can't have it both ways.

Answer (score 4):

After being in this situation myself, @kontiki’s answer really gave me a head start, but in his solution, the modifiers we apply to the image won’t work, so this is my approach:

We create a function that returns a String instead of an Image:

```
func safeSystemImage(_ systemName: String) -> String {
    let image = "\(systemName).square.fill"
    
    return UIImage(systemName: image) != nil ? image : "" // ← The image you want in case it doesn't exist.
}
```

Usage:

```
Image(systemName: safeSystemImage(yourImage))
```

This way we can change it’s color, size, etc…

Answer (score -2):

Use an API Availability Check for each specific symbol.

For example:

```swift
if #available(iOS 17.0, *) {
    Image(systemName: "circle.dotted.and.circle")
} else {
    Image(systemName: "network")
}
```

Use the [SF Symbols app](https://developer.apple.com/sf-symbols/) to determine the platforms for which a symbol is available. Select a symbol in the SF Symbols app. Choose View > Inspectors > Show Info Inspector (<kbd>⌥⌘1</kbd>). Then see the Availability heading.